# What's the difference between these two MongoDB $regex syntaxes?

Tags: regex, mongodb

Let's say I want to search for all users containing the string "foo" in their username. Is there any practical difference between the following?

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*foo.*"}})
```

And:

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : "foo"}})
```

Both seems to work. But can somebody explain the difference please?

Comment: Yes, `"foo"` will find `foo` quicker.

Answer (score 6):

Both will work, but `.*foo.*` needs more time to return the valid match due to *backtracking* that happens with `.*foo.*`.

Compare "some foo text" with [`/.*foo.*/`](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gJ0/1):

[image]

and [`/foo/`](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gJ0/2):

[image]

Note that it is the first `.*` before `foo` in the first regex that makes it slower, because the `.` can match both `f` and `o`s.